# EF Core 3: entity creation failed, bad creation order

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to add a new DbUserInfo2 in my DB. It has a PostalAddress child table. For some reason, i need to set the UserId of DbUserInfo2 manually.

This is not working in ef core 3.1, it used to work in ef core 2.2.

What is happening is that EF is trying to create the new PostalAddress row before it creates the DbUserInfo2 row. Thus leading to a foreign key .

Any idea what i've done wrong ?

```
public class DbUserInfo2
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DbPostalAddress2 PostalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class DbPostalAddress2
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PostalAddressId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

void TestInsert(MyDbContext db)
{
    var user = new DbUserInfo2 { UserId = 22, PostalAddress = new DbPostalAddress2() };
    db.Add(user);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to have bothered you. Creating and applying a new migration after updating the mysql library version fixed the issue.